# magento 2 how to render a custom collection like category page

Tags: magento2

I write a custom module with a search form with multiple select input field and with a file index.phtml to render the results page, like the image below:

[image]

But in this page I would view also the left sidebar with layered navigation as in the category page (I would red boxes also in my custom collection results page)

[image]

This is my code to create a specific collection:

```
$collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$collection->addCategoriesFilter(['in' => intval($categoria)]);
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('modello', ['eq' => $modello]);
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('cilindrata', ['eq' => $cilindrata]);
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('anno', ['eq' => $anno]);
$collection->load();
```

This is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="TBRB\Engine\Block\Index" name="engine_index_index" template="TBRB_Engine::index.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
</page>
```

And this is index.phtml to render the results:

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$_productCollection = $block->getData('custom_parameter');
$_helper = $this->helper(Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output::class);
$_block = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct');
?>

<?php if (empty($_productCollection)) :?>
    <div class="message info empty"><div><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('We can\'t find products matching the selection.')) ?></div></div>
<?php else :?>
    <?php
        echo $_block->getToolbarHtml();
        echo $_block->getAdditionalHtml();

        //GRID MODE
        $viewMode = 'grid';
        $image = 'category_page_grid';
        $showDescription = true;
        $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::SHORT_VIEW;
        $pos = $block->getPositioned();
    ?>
    <div class="products wrapper <?= /* @noEscape */ $viewMode ?> products-<?= /* @noEscape */ $viewMode ?>">
        <?php $iterator = 1; ?>
        <ol class="products list items product-items">
            <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $key => $value) : ?>
                <?php $_product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($value['entity_id']); ?>
                <?= /* @noEscape */ ($iterator++ == 1) ? '<li class="item product product-item">' : '</li><li class="item product product-item">' ?>
                <div class="product-item-info" data-container="product-<?= /* @noEscape */ $viewMode ?>">
                    <?php
                    $productImage = $_block->getImage($_product, $image);
                    if ($pos != null) {
                        $position = ' style="left:' . $productImage->getWidth() . 'px;'
                            . 'top:' . $productImage->getHeight() . 'px;"';
                    }
                    ?>
                    <a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($_product->getProductUrl()) ?>"
                       class="product photo product-item-photo"
                       tabindex="-1">
                        <?php echo $productImage->toHtml()  ?>
                    </a>
                    <div class="product details product-item-details">
                        <?php
                        $_productNameStripped = $block->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true);
                        ?>
                        <strong class="product name product-item-name">
                            <a class="product-item-link"
                               href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($_product->getProductUrl()) ?>">
                                <?= /* @noEscape */ $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?>
                            </a>
                        </strong>

                        <?php if ($_product->isAvailable()) :?>
                            <div class="stock available"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('In stock')) ?></span></div>
                        <?php else :?>
                            <div class="stock unavailable"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Out of stock')) ?></span></div>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                        <?= $_block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, $templateType) ?>
                        <?= $_block->getProductPrice($_product) ?>
                        <?= $_block->getProductDetailsHtml($_product) ?>

                        <div class="product-item-inner">
                            <div class="product actions product-item-actions"<?= strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-actions') ? $block->escapeHtmlAttr($position) : '' ?>>
                                <div class="actions-primary"<?= strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-primary') ? $block->escapeHtmlAttr($position) : '' ?>>
                                    <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()) :?>
                                        <?php $postParams = $_block->getAddToCartPostParams($_product); ?>
                                        <form data-role="tocart-form"
                                              data-product-sku="<?= $block->escapeHtml($_product->getSku()) ?>"
                                              action="<?= $block->escapeUrl($postParams['action']) ?>"
                                              method="post">
                                            <input type="hidden"
                                                   name="product"
                                                   value="<?= /* @noEscape */ $postParams['data']['product'] ?>">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED; ?>" value="<?php echo $postParams['data'][\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED]; ?>">
                                            <?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
                                            <button type="submit"
                                                    title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Add to Cart')) ?>"
                                                    class="action tocart primary">
                                                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')) ?></span>
                                            </button>
                                        </form>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </div>
                                <div data-role="add-to-links" class="actions-secondary"<?= strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-secondary') ? $block->escapeHtmlAttr($position) : '' ?>>
                                    <?php if ($addToBlock = $block->getChildBlock('addto')) :?>
                                        <?= $addToBlock->setProduct($_product)->getChildHtml() ?>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <?php if ($showDescription) :?>
                                <div class="product description product-item-description">
                                    <?= /* @noEscape */ $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getShortDescription(), 'short_description') ?>
                                    <a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($_product->getProductUrl()) ?>"
                                       title="<?= /* @noEscape */ $_productNameStripped ?>"
                                       class="action more"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Learn More')) ?></a>
                                </div>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?= ($iterator == count($_productCollection)+1) ? '</li>' : '' ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ol>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Thank you!!

Comment: Any solution...?